# Optimizing Powershell Script to find old files and delete them on DFS replicated folders

Tags: file, powershell, replication, file-management

Here is the story. I have a fileshare that is replicated between 2 servers located in different places in the world. DFS will not replicate a file if it has only been viewed, but I wouldn't want to delete that file/folder because it was used within the time period I have set (7 days). So to make sure that I don't remove still used files I have to check both locations for their LastAccessTime.

I currently have this

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
$PathOne = "FirstPath"
$PathTwo = "SecondPath"
$ToBeDeletedPathOne = Get-ChildItem -Path $PathOne -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastAccessTime -lt $limit }
$TobeDeletedPathTwo = Get-ChildItem -Path $PathTwo -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastAccessTime -lt $limit }
$DiffObjects = Compare-Object -referenceobject $ToBeDeletedPathOne -differenceobject $ToBeDeletedPathTwo -IncludeEqual
$ToBeDeletedOverall = DiffObjects | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="}
```

After this, I loop through and delete the files that are marked for deletion by both locations.

Part of the problem I have is that there are a tremendous amount of files and this can take a very long time. So I wanted to make it better/faster. My idea is to have this script run the scan as a different script on each FS server and wait for them to return the output. That way it can scan on the local machine easier than remotely and it would scan both locations simultaneously.

The other part of the problem comes in with the fact that I have no idea how to do this. I will continue to work on this and if I solve it, I will post here in case anyone in the future finds this useful.

Comment: It sounds like you have a process that is working but you are trying to speed it up, is that correct?  Can you run the process on the local machines and save the results in a file or database that is available to all machines? Would that help speed things along?

Comment: Yes this currently works but is slow. While storing the data in a database and then performing queries against it would help speed up the process it wouldn't be by much. The major problem here is that the scans don't run in unison and they are what is taking so long since it has a lot to scan. My ideal solution is to have a central script start a smaller scanning script on each machine locally with something like start-job, which is what I'm currently tinkering with. Those smaller scripts would scan and report back with what they would delete and the central script would delete those files.

Comment: I would suggest doing a `Get-Help New-Job -Full` and `Get-Help Get-job -Full` to read up on running things in parallel as background jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You could run everything locally. Copy the script to the machines you want (make a script to copy them if you need to) then use something like PSTools to kick them off on the local machines. This should essentially run the script simultaneously on all machines.

Comment: Something would have to be remote because they are two separate servers in two locations. One is in dallas and the other is New Orleans. I am currently attempting to have this script ignore scanning and just run a seperate script on each server that just scans the files by running them as a new background job and setting it to wait for completion.